# EPL & La Liga Datasets

Tags: dataset

I'm looking for a dataset which will show the total number of games played by each player on every club in EPL and La Liga. I check Kaggle, dataset, github and football.db. I can't seem to find the data which shows the total number of games played by each player.
Does anyone know where I find that dataset?

Comment: a while back I believe ESPN had some similar data available - i don't know if it's still available but take a look and let us know! I (and i'm sure others) will love to play with that data.

Comment: that's a good lead, thanks. Otherwise I'm gonna get creative and create the dataset myself and help others who are looking for the data.